# Adafruit feather M0 wifi firmware update

Tags: wifi, adafruit

I just noticed that the firmware on the m0 wifi might need updating but says not to use the provided updater, how do you update the firmware so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**
Here's what I did... (maybe some steps not necessary, but this worked for me)

1) First run the "CheckWifi101FirmwareVersion" found in the Arduino WiFi 101 library.

- NOTE: You need to add in the `WiFi.setPins(8,7,4,2);` after `void setup() {`
- If it's backlevel (before 19.4.4), then

2) Download the Adafruit WiFi101 Updater on github (
   https://github.com/adafruit/WiFi101-FirmwareUpdater/archive/master.zip
   )

3) Install the "FirmwareUpdater" from the Arduino WiFi 101 Library

- Add in the recommended changes (even if it's the defaults)

  ```
  #define WINC_CS 8
  #define WINC_IRQ 7
  #define WINC_RST 4
  #define WINC_EN 2
  ```

  and the usual `WiFi.setPins(8,7,4,2)` after void `setup() {`

4) Copy the firmware you wish to flash to same directory as "winc1500-uploader.exe"

5) Run the command:

> winc1500-uploader.exe --port [YourComPort] --firmware [YourFirmwareFileName].bin

So for example I did:

> winc1500-uploader.exe --port COM9 --firmware m2m_aio_2b0.bin

Comment: NOTE: Check your board version.  It could also be:

winc1500-uploader.exe --port COM9 --firmware m2m_aio_3a0.bin